# R cutting two data.frames based on intervals and merging

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I cut two data frames based on their intervals and merge them?

#### Data Frame 1

```
read.table(textConnection(
"   from to Lith  
1   0   1.2 GRN   
2   1.2 5.0 GDI   
"), header=TRUE)
```

#### Data Frame 2

```
read.table(textConnection(
"   from to Weath  
1   0  1.1  HW  
2   1.1 2.9 SW 
3   2.9 5.0 HW  
"), header=TRUE)
```

#### Resulting Data Frame

```
  from to Weath Lith 
1 0.0 1.1 HW  GRN
2 1.1 1.2 SW  GRN
3 1.2 2.9 SW  GDI
4 2.9 5.0 HW  GDI
```

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please explain "How do I cut two data frame"?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta sorry about the confusion guys. Was at the office when I made this. The solutions provided are correct.I couldn't think of a way to do this using R until you showed me. I thought there was a 'quick' and already made function in R but has not.

Comment: @Metrics I should have thought of a more definitive title. What I wanted to do was to split the intervals of a data.frame based on the intervals of another data.frame and vice versa. THe data.frame is then combined or merged based on this.

Comment: @geodex, it is quite alright.  Dont sweat it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good place to use the `roll` feature of `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 = data.table(read.table(textConnection(
"   from to Lith  
1   0   1.2 GRN   
2   1.2 5.0 GDI   
"), header=TRUE))

dt2 = data.table(read.table(textConnection(
"   from to Weath  
1   0  1.1  HW  
2   1.1 2.9 SW 
3   2.9 5.0 HW  
"), header=TRUE))

# set the key for the join
setkey(dt1, from)
setkey(dt2, from)

# get the unique id's
ids = sort(unique(c(dt1$from, dt2$from, dt1$to, dt2$to)))

# make a table of final from-to, keyed by 'final.from'
from.to = data.table(final.from = head(ids, -1),
                     final.to = tail(ids, -1),
                     key = 'final.from')

# join with a roll and combine together
result = dt1[from.to, roll = Inf][, Weath := dt2[from.to, roll = Inf]$Weath][,
             `:=`(to = final.to, final.to = NULL)]
#   from  to Lith Weath
#1:  0.0 1.1  GRN    HW
#2:  1.1 1.2  GRN    SW
#3:  1.2 2.9  GDI    SW
#4:  2.9 5.0  GDI    HW
```

Comment: Follow-up question, what if you have multiple columns for each data.frame and not just one?

Comment: @geodex you may need to do more than one rolling merge per `data.table`; I suggest trying a few things along these lines and posting another SO question with attempted solutions if nothing works

Answer (score 2):

It's not altogether clear how you want to "cut" the two data sets, if by lowest matching `from` value, or complete match across a row.

Try the following:

```
library(data.table)
ft <- c("from", "to")
allVals <- unique(sort(unlist(c(df1[, ft], df2[, ft]))))
results <- data.table(from=head(allVals, -1), to=allVals[-1L])

results[, 
  c("Lith", "Weath") := 
     lapply(list(
       df1[from >= df1[["from"]] & to <= df1[["to"]], "Lith"], 
       df2[from >= df2[["from"]] & to <= df2[["to"]], "Weath"]
       # alternatively, someting like:
       #  df1[which.max(from >= df1[["from"]]), "Lith"],
       #  df2[which.max(from >= df2[["from"]]), "Weath"]
     ), as.character)
  , by=list(from, to)]

results

   from  to Lith Weath
1:  0.0 1.1  GRN    HW
2:  1.1 1.2  GRN    SW
3:  1.2 2.9  GDI    SW
4:  2.9 5.0  GDI    HW
```

Comment: hi ricardo, would want to "cut" and match the intervals on both data frames to match each other. Seems to be the code is not working

Comment: Hello @geodex you have not indicated neither (1) what you have attempted nor (2) how specifically you are defining `cut` and meanwhile at least two people have spent their time attempting to help you.  Have a look at @eddi's answer and perhaps that is more helpful.  Otherwise, I dont know what other advise to offer.