# Merging two data.frames with overlapping intervals

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I merge a data.frame from data.frames with overlapping intervals?

#### Data Frame 1

```
read.table(textConnection(
 "   from to Lith Form 
1   0   1.2 GRN   BCM
2   1.2 5.0 GDI   BDI
"), header=TRUE)
```

#### Data Frame 2

```
read.table(textConnection(
"   from to Weath Str
1   0  1.1  HW ES
2   1.1 2.9 SW VS
3   2.9 5.0 HW ST 
"), header=TRUE)
```

#### Resulting Data Frame

```
from to Weath Str Lith Form
1 0.0 1.1 HW ES GRN  BCM
2 1.1 1.2 SW VS GRN  BCM
3 1.2 2.9 SW VS GDI  BDI
4 2.9 5.0 HW ST GDI  BDI
```

Comment: Isn't this nearly the same as your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390337/r-cutting-two-data-frames-based-on-intervals-and-merging

Comment: yes almost. the previous one has only one other column. Im trying to figure this one out using data.table but couldnt figure out the roll parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. It's similar to the answer of eddi ([R cutting two data.frames based on intervals and merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390337/r-cutting-two-data-frames-based-on-intervals-and-merging)), but you can have as many columns in your data.frames as you like.

```
# change your data to data.table
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key='from')
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key='from')
# skeleton for joined data.table
dt <- data.table(from=sort(unique(c(dt1[,from], dt2[,from]))), 
                 to=sort(unique(c(dt1[,to], dt2[,to]))), 
                 key='from')
# function to join skeleton with data.table
j1 <- function(dt, dt1){
  dt3 <- dt1[dt, roll=TRUE]
  dt3[,':='(to=to.1, to.1=NULL)]
  setkey(dt3, from, to)
  return(dt3)
}
# merge two data.tables
j1(dt, dt2)[j1(dt, dt1)]
```

---

In v1.9.3, recently *overlap joins* (or *interval joins*) has been implemented. With this, I think your task can be accomplished as follows (assuming your data.frames are `df1` and `df2`):

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.3+
setDT(df1)  ## convert to data.table without copy
setDT(df2)

setkey(df2, from, to)
ans = foverlaps(df1, df2, type="any")
ans = ans[, `:=`(from = pmax(from, i.from), to = pmin(to, i.to))]
ans = ans[, `:=`(i.from=NULL, i.to=NULL)][from <= to]
#    from  to Weath Str Lith Form
# 1:  0.0 1.1    HW  ES  GRN  BCM
# 2:  1.1 1.2    SW  VS  GRN  BCM
# 3:  1.2 2.9    SW  VS  GDI  BDI
# 4:  2.9 5.0    HW  ST  GDI  BDI
```

Comment: foverlaps is really cool!